# Marshall object attribute generates compiler error

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling

I'm working on a brigde class to work with a unmanaged c++ library. I've a problem with the following (reduced) example code:

```
    ref class ManagedClass
    {
    private:
        UnManagedClass* m_UnManaged;
        String^  m_someString;
    public:
        UserAgent_Managed(String^ someString) 
        { 
            m_someString = someString;

            // Compiler error
            // Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error C2665   'msclr::interop::marshal_as': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument 
            // types    

            std::string unManagedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(m_someString);

            // Following works 
            // std::string unManagedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(someString);


            m_UnManaged = new UnManagedClass(unManagedString); 
        }
    };
```

When I call `std::string unManagedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(m_someString);` with the object attribute `m_someString`, the compiler tells me that there is no matching `marshal_as` method signature. If I perform the same with the `someString`parameter the compiler doesn't throw an error. What am I missing? Both `m_someString`and `someString` have the type `String^`.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `marshal_as()` function is not very friendly, it is missing an overload to allow this code to compile.  You can hone down the problem by looking at the IntelliSense popup that shows which overloads are available.  The one you are trying to use is the 4th:

```
  std::string marshal_as<std::string, System::String^>(System::String^ const & _from_obj)
```

The devil is in `&`, an *unmanaged* reference.  Yes, an unmanaged reference to a managed object reference, mind blown :)  But perfectly legal in C++/CLI, at runtime this argument turns into a raw pointer to the object reference.

It would have compiled if the template offered a `System::String^ % _from_obj` overload.  It doesn't.  The distinction between `%` and `&` matters a lot in C++/CLI, `%` declares a *managed* reference.  Called a "tracking reference" in the docs.  One that the garbage collector knows about and can update when it compacts the GC heap.  Otherwise semantically completely identical to an unmanaged reference.

That the GC cannot update a `&` reference is the hang-up here.  The compiler outright forbids generating unmanaged pointers to members of a managed type, other than through pin_ptr<>.  It is far too dangerous, the garbage collector can kick in any time, even while the marshal_as() function is executing.  Triggered by, say, another thread that allocates objects.  And move the ManagedClass object, invalidating any raw pointers to the object.  Having the function continue to use the outdated pointer at runtime will make the function produce garbage and possibly corrupt the GC heap.

The `someString` object reference is very different, it is stored on the stack or a processor register and cannot change when a collection occurs.  So no complaints from the compiler.

You already have a good workaround here, the constructor argument is good as-is.  But usually you have to provide one explicitly and store the member value into a local variable.  In other words, write something like this:

```
   auto temp = this->m_someString;   // Intentional temporary
   auto str = marshal_as<std::string>(temp);
```